# Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/click_0.4.46+17.10.20170607.3-0~622~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb

Tags: command-line, server, syslinux

I use Ubuntu 14.04. When I run `apt-get -f install` I get this output:

```
(Reading database ... 314897 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../click_0.4.46+17.10.20170607.3-0~622~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to issue method call: Unit click-system-hooks.service not loaded.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to issue method call: Unit click-system-hooks.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/click_0.4.46+17.10.20170607.3-0~622~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Failed to issue method call: Unit click-system-hooks.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status click-system-hooks.service' for details.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/click_0.4.46+17.10.20170607.3-0~622~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: So what is the question? Just posting code isn't enough :(

Comment: Run `systemctl daemon-reload` and try again

Comment: why i am getting this error whenevre i am running the apt-get -f install

Comment: systemctl daemon-reload still not working

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on 16.10 and used:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/click
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

After that things started working again.

Comment: This suggestion was enough to get `$ sudo apt --fix-broken install` at least moving again for me, but was not enough to resolve the particular broken state I had. I didn't want to have the `click` package SDK on this install anymore so using `$ sudo apt remove -f click click-dev python3-click python3-click-package` were able to resolve the broken state of the python3 `click` package.